# Call ViewHelper from Controller

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-extensions

i`m trying to call a ViewHelper Function from within a Controller in Typo3 (to add some additional header data)

Base is the [Yag Gallery](https://github.com/YAG-Gallery/yag).

I edited the [ItemListController.php](https://github.com/YAG-Gallery/yag/blob/master/Classes/Controller/ItemListController.php) and added the following:

```
$pager = $this->extListContext->getPagerCollection();
$prevLinkUid = $pager->getPreviousPage();
$arg = Tx_YAG_ViewHelpers_Namespace_GPArrayViewHelper::render([page:$prevLinkUid], $pager)
$test = '<link rel="test" href="' . $arg . '">';
$this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData($test);
```

The addAdditionalHeaderData function works well with other data (e.g. `$prevLinkUid`, so this part is functioning well).

If i understand the syntax of [GPArrayViewHelper::render](https://github.com/YAG-Gallery/yag/blob/428e81e264e18523ecca4df61d9236775f13b26c/Classes/ViewHelpers/Namespace/GPArrayViewHelper.php) correctly, i need a pageUid as first argument and the pagerCollection as second argument (derived from this call within [Resources/Private/Partials/Pager/Default.html](https://github.com/YAG-Gallery/yag/blob/428e81e264e18523ecca4df61d9236775f13b26c/Resources/Private/Partials/Pager/Default.html)

```
 <extlist:link.action controller="{controller}" action="{action}" arguments="{extlist:namespace.GPArray(object:'{pagerCollection}' arguments:'page:{pager.previousPage}')}"><span>&lt;</span>       </extlist:link.action>
```

)

However - if i try this Controller my page won't render, so i assume there is something wrong with the php code / function call, maybe even the syntax of the key value pair/first argument? Sorry, i'm not a professional in php

Any ideas how can i achieve this? I read that it may be difficult to use ViewHelpers from within other controllers?

Answer (score 2):

there is a ViewHelperInvoker class which you can use to render a viewhelper in a controller:

```
    $viewHelperInvoker = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\ViewHelperInvoker::class);
    $result = $viewHelperInvoker->invoke(
        \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Format\CurrencyViewHelper::class,
        [ 'currencySign' => '€' ],
        new \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContext(),
        function() {
            return 12345.67;
        }
    );
```

https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/blob/master/src/Core/ViewHelper/ViewHelperInvoker.php

Answer (score 0):

Viewhelpers are not supposed to be used outside of Fluid templates.

However, there might be an easier way to achieve what you want, e.g. with [`HeaderAssets`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/singlehtml/#feature-73409-auto-render-assets-sections-in-fluid-template-with-controller). This way you can easily add snippets to the `<head>` of your page from within a controller action or page template.

Comment: If i unterstand this right, this is for typo3 8.x.x., correct?
Haven't mentioned, i use typo3 7.6.x

Comment: Correct, this is for TYPO3 v8 and newer only.

Answer (score 0):

Please really don't to that. What you can do is using the `PageRenderer`. E.g. using

```
$pageRenderer = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PageRenderer::class);
$pageRenderer->addHeaderData($headerData);
```

Comment: Okay, good hint, but actually this doesn't help me with my problem, because i have trouble getting the correct `$headerData`, not with adding them to my `<head>` section